# Python - combine regex patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have a large text and the aim is to select all 10-character strings for which the first character is a letter and the last character is a digit.

I am a python rookie and what I managed to achieve is to find all 10-character strings:

```
ten_char = re.findall(r"\D(\w{10})\D", pdfdoc)
```

Question is how can I put together my other conditions: apart from a 10-character string, I am looking for one where the first character is a letter and the last character is a digit.

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: You can use `[A-Za-z]` and `[0-9]` to tell it the character at this position should be an alphabetical character or a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it, do:

```
r'\b([a-zA-Z]\S{8}\d)\b'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM7lI7/2)

Python demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> txt="""\
... Should match:
... a123456789 aA34567s89 zzzzzzzer9
... 
... Not match:
... 1123456789 aA34567s8a zzzzzzer9 zzzxzzzze99"""
>>> re.findall(r'\b([a-zA-Z]\S{8}\d)\b', txt)
['a123456789', 'aA34567s89', 'zzzzzzzer9']
```

Answer (score 2):

`([a-z].{8}[0-9])`

Will ask for 1 alphabetical char, 8 other character and finally 1 number.

**JS Demo**

```js
var re = /([a-z].{8}[0-9])/gi; 
var str = 'Aasdf23423423423423423b423423423423423';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
     console.log(m[0]);
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/gI8jZ4/1

Comment: Don't use `[.]` in the middle. It can match whitespace. Use `\w`.

Comment: You might want to use `\w` for all non-whitespace characters, or `[a-zA-Z]` to include capitalized alphanumerics -- and don't forget about non-ASCII.

Comment: @DawidGrabowski and Christian, I can edit it but that would only include `any letter, number or underscore.` and I don't see that reflecting the question at this moment. Could you please ellaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regex for this. Regular string manipulation is more clear in my opinion (though I haven't tested the following code).

```
def get_useful_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                if len(word) == 10 and word[0].isalpha() and word[-1].isdigit():
                    yield word


for useful_word in get_useful_words('tmp.txt'):
    print(useful_word)
```

Comment: @DawidGrabowski Could you please explain the inefficiencies? I'm not caching a regular expression, but I'm also not reading the whole file into memory at one time. The question specified a large text file.

Comment: Memory wise I agree but that's just gonna be slower comparing to regex.

Comment: Personally, I don't find this more clear. This seems like the perfect use for a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for a great discussion and interesting suggestions. Very first post on stack overflow, but wow...what a community you are!

In fact, using:

```
r'\b([a-zA-Z]\S{8}\d)'
```

solved my problem very nicely. Really appreciated all your comments.

Comment: Be sure to use `r'\b([a-zA-Z]\S{8}\d)\b'` or you will also match words longer than 10 characters that have a matching prefix...